# jQuery .each append first then second value etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling for a while now with this.

I got 2 'tabs' the first tab is visible and the second tab is hidden.

What i need is, when i add more select elements and chance the value of that select element and i click 'next' i need to add to the first 'Content:' with the value 'Foo' and to the second 'Content:' 'Bar' for example.
But now i get 'Content: Foo Bar' and 'Content: Foo Bar' every time.

First take a look at this fiddle please [Click here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9XaN/4/)

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="tab1">
    <p>
        <select>
            <option>Foo</option>
            <option>Bar</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="add">add</a>
    <input type="button" value="next" class="next add_content" />
</div>

<div id="tab2">
    <p>Content: <span></span></p>
    <input type="button" value="prev" class="prev" />
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().prev().show();
});

$("a.add").click(function(){
    var row = $("#tab1").children("p").first().clone();
    var row2 = $("#tab2").children("p").first().clone();

    row.insertBefore(this);
    row2.insertAfter("#tab2 p:last");

    return false;
});

$(".add_content").click(function() {
    $("#tab1 select option:selected").each(function() {
       var content = $(this).val();
        $("#tab2 p span").append(content + " ");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index to update the span

```
$(".add_content").click(function () {
    var spans = $("#tab2 p span");
    $("#tab1 select option:selected").each(function (i) {
        var content = $(this).val();
        spans.eq(i).text(content); // as suggested by @RaphaëlAlthaus
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/etCa8/)

Comment: @Julez it fetches the the span element at the same index as the current select... like first span for first select, second span for 2nd select etv

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus Thanks for the great tip!! that solved a other problem for me. i was thinking about emtpy the span every time i click on "prev". But this is a alot easier

Answer (score 1):

another option just change your function like below. You can try this should work.

```
$(".add_content").click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#tab1 select option:selected").each(function() {
       var content = $(this).val();
        $("#tab2 p span:eq("+i+")").text(content + " ");
        ++i;
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle : [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9XaN/6/)

eq(0) is just like selection the 0th or 1st element its a index

Comment: Thanks this also worked, shows me a other option to. Good to know.

Comment: If it is useful for you give it a upvote so that others can understand that it is also a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are adding the content to every span in div#tab_2

You need to target them individually using something like [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Change your click handler to this:

```
$(".add_content").click(function() {
    $("#tab1 select").each(function(i) {
       var content = $(this).val();
       $("#tab2 p span").eq(i).append(content + " ");
    });
});
```